# Neo4j max function

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to search **the latest Ubuntu version** in [the “Network and IT Management” database from Neo4j sandbox](https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2/).

So I wrote this piece of code:

```
MATCH (os:OS) WHERE os.name = "Ubuntu" RETURN max(os.versions)
```

But the result is:

```
["14.04", "16.04", "16.10", "17.04"]
```

I suppose I have got all the version. How can I solve it?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sandbox you refer to only contains a single Ubuntu `OS`, so naturally the result only returns a single record with that node. It is a bit tricky because the value of the node property `versions` is in itself a list.

`max` is an aggregation function which is applied to result (not the value of a SINGLE property).

Imagine having 3 nodes matching `WHERE os.name = "Ubuntu"` with individual versions. It can be simulated like the following:

```
UNWIND [["14.04", "16.04", "16.10", "17.04"],
        ["18.04", "18.10", "19.04", "19.10"],
        ["20.04", "20.10", "21.04", "21.10"]] AS versions
RETURN max(versions)
```

which will return: `["20.04", "20.10", "21.04", "21.10"]`.

If you are indeed interested in the individual versions on a specific node it can be achived with unwind:

```
MATCH (os:OS) WHERE os.name = "Ubuntu"
UNWIND os.versions as version
RETURN max(version)
```

which will return `"17.04"`.

Comment: Tnank you a lot! That was very useful (: